# How to add Roslyn code-analyzers to Unity project? (for Unity versions below 2020)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, nuget-package, csproj, roslyn-code-analysis

When I install Roslyn code-analyzer as NuGet-package for a project (say `Assembly-CSharp`) of solution of my Unity-project, 2 things happen:

- package is installed to `Packages` folder at Unity-project root
- and lines like `<Analyzer Include="packages\SomeAnalyzer.1.2.3\analyzers\dotnet\cs\SomeAnalyzer.dll" />` are added to the `.csproj` file (in our case `Assembly-CSharp.csproj`)

The problem is - **Unity regenerates** `.csproj` file (f.e. when you add or remove .cs files or when you close and reopen Unity editor). Regeneration of `.csproj` erases added lines, mentioned above. And analyzers stop working.

Looks like [for Unity 2020 the problem is solved](https://docs.unity3d.com/2020.2/Documentation/Manual/roslyn-analyzers.html). But my project is on Unity 2019 & could not be updated to 2020 now. So I my question is: Is it possible to add code analyzer to Unity-project and make it work for Unity versions below 2020?

Answer (score 3):

Ok, I've found some solutions:

**#1** Code with smell, but it works (but most likely one of the next two solution is better for you):

([found it here](https://github.com/vad710/UnityEngineAnalyzer/issues/27#issuecomment-399764272))
We accept that Unity erases lines about installed package from `.csproj` file. But we use a Unity hook `AssetPostprocessor.OnGeneratedCSProjectFiles` to "manually" rewrite `.csproj` returning those lines.

**#2** Much more elegant way (I chose it)

([found it here](https://rider-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360002398539/comments/360001394920))
We just put the `Directory.Build.props` file near our `.sln` & put (manually, but once) in it lines, which Unity removes from `.csproj`. That's all.

*#Note:* if you want to analyzer work not for all projects, you could use [Condition for Property group](https://github.com/JetBrains/resharper-unity/issues/1835#issuecomment-701373444).

**#3** I didn't check it, but may be it will become the best solution for you

([found it here](https://github.com/vad710/UnityEngineAnalyzer/commit/562ff51626b6808cb4ee5410057f2c078c38609b))
We should add `Assets/csc.rsp` file which references analyzer dlls & ruleset in such way:

```
-a:"full_or_relative_path_to_UnityEngineAnalyzer.dll"
-ruleset:"full_or_relative_path_to_rules.ruleset"
```

It may works only with Rider (IDE), 'cos requirements stated as:

> Applies to Unity 2019.2+ with Rider package 1.1.3+

Answer (score 1):

Been looking at the feature of analysers for unity, on a 2019.4 version, the csproj files do get generated correctly without any csc.rsp files if I follow the following rules from unity (from the link you posted) :

- Move the three .dll files into the Assets folder (or any folder nested in the Assets folder) in your Unity project.
- In the Editor, select the .dll file. In the Plugin Inspector, under Select platforms for plugin, disable Any Platform. Under Include platforms, disable Editor and Standalone platforms.
- Then, give all of the DLLs a new label called RoslynAnalyzer.

But now I do not get the warnings I was looking for in the console of Unity. The warnings are there on a 2020 version though. Are you able to see the warnings from the new analysers in a 2019 version of unity ?

Comment: Hi, @punkyman. Wellcome to S.O. ;) No, I didn't find a way to show analyzer warnings at Unity 2019 console. They are shown only at IDE. Looks like it's possible only since Unity 2020 (may be 2020.2).
PS: You probably posted this as an answer, 'cos your reputation isn't ehough yet to post comments. But, when StackOverflow let you to comment, such text should be posted as a comment (not as an answer)